# How to append a row in table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to append a new row in my table using Javascript but the new row should be like my previous rows.

I am using CSS to format my rows.

Comment: If you want to do this using javascript is there some particular reason why your question is tagged with `java`? Also it would be helpful if you showed your HTML structure as well as what you have tried so far to tackle the problem so that we can have some base for discussion.

Comment: When you decide on an answer, make sure you click the checkmark next to it to "accept" it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jQuery it will be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table tr:last").clone().appendTo("table");
})
```

Replacing table with the id or class of your table (unless you only plan to have one table).

Answer (score 2):

Using good old [`Node.cloneNode(deep)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode) along with [`HTMLTableElement.rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.rows):

HTML:

```
<table id="foo">
    <tbody id="bar">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
var rows = foo.rows;
var lastRow = rows[rows.length-1];
var newRow = cloneRow(lastRow, true, bar);

function cloneRow(row, append, parent)
{
    var newRow = row.cloneNode(true); 
    if(append)
    {
        if(parent)
        {
            parent.appendChild(newRow);
        }
    }
    return newRow;
}
```

For comparison's sake, here's my code juxtaposed against the jQuery answer: http://jsperf.com/dom-methods-vs-jquery-with-tables

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your row has a css style of `.row`

So you could just use DOM methods to create a new `tr`, add the `class="row"` then add the appropriate amount of `td`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that avoids the use of the `cloneNode` method, and that **do not copy** the content, data or events of the previous last row, just its CSS attributes and class names.

The new row will have the same number of cell as the previous last row.

```
var lastRow = myTable.rows[myTable.rows.length-1];
var newRow = myTable.insertRow();
newRow.className = lastRow.className;
newRow.style.cssText = lastRow.style.cssText;
for (var i = 0; i < lastRow.cells.length; i++) {
    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(i);
    newCell.className = lastRow.cells[i].className;
    newCell.style.cssText = lastRow.cells[i].style.cssText;
}
```